# Filter record of everyminite based on seconds Using Mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have one query and below is the example for my scenario of mysql table:

```
-----------------------------------------
Date                   phone_number    
-----------------------------------------  
2015-11-03 00:00:20     123465789
2015-11-03 00:00:20     457894568
2015-11-03 00:00:35     123213213
2015-11-03 00:00:40     123465789
2015-11-03 00:00:55     345435543
.
.
.
2015-11-03 00:01:05     123465789
2015-11-03 00:01:05     4564646654
2015-11-03 00:01:05     7897978789
2015-11-03 00:01:07     2322323232
.
.
.
```

I want to get max number of records based on seconds.

For example, on 3rd of Nov, first minute there are total 5 records but I want to filter the records of 20th sec which is 2 records(Maximum record for that minute).

```
2015-11-03 00:00:20     123465789
2015-11-03 00:00:20     457894568
2015-11-03 00:00:35     123213213
2015-11-03 00:00:40     123465789
2015-11-03 00:00:55     345435543
```

same way, on first minute there are 4 records, but number of  max record is 3  because at 01:05 there are total 3 records.

```
2015-11-03 00:01:05     123465789
2015-11-03 00:01:05     4564646654
2015-11-03 00:01:05     7897978789
2015-11-03 00:01:07     2322323232
```

So I need to group by record of every second and then get max value of that minute.I want to get this record for single day.

Can any one suggest how can I achieve this with mysql query?

Comment: can you set up sql fiddle. for this.. Please share the expected output

Comment: >on 3rd of Nov, first minute there are total 5 records

So what should be the output.. Should it contain all 5 entries or only one

Comment: > @subin, how can i create fiddle for this ?
on 3rd of Nov, first minute there are total 4 records but on 00:01:05 sec there are total 3 record so i need that first minute max record for group by each seconds.

llike 00:01:05 -> 3 records
00:01:07 -> 1 records
so for this minutes max records  is 3

Comment: edit question with sample output?

Comment: So you need `minute wise` and `count` for it right?

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode nearly. The op wants only the highest count per minute

Comment: Yes highest count for per minute.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88aca8/4 Please check it gives correct out put..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM
(SELECT T1.`tdate` as tdate,COUNT(T1.`tdate`) AS Occurance
    FROM
    table_name T1 
    GROUP BY T1.`tdate`) T1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT T1.`tdate` as tdate,COUNT(T1.`tdate`) AS Occurance
    FROM
    table_name T1 
    GROUP BY T1.`tdate`) T2 
 ON CONCAT(DATE(T1.`tdate`),HOUR(T1.`tdate`),minute(T1.`tdate`))=CONCAT(DATE(T2.`tdate`),HOUR(T2.`tdate`),minute(T2.`tdate`)) AND T1.`Occurance`<T2.`Occurance`
WHERE T2.`Occurance` IS NULL AND T1.`tdate` BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-11-05'
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88aca8/5).

Hope this helps

Comment: Upvoted for providing a CREATE and INSERT statements (which the OP really should have done in the first place)

Comment: The returned tdate is just an arbitrary tdate per minute, not necessarily the one with the maximum occurence.

Comment: `returned tdate is just an arbitrary tdate per minute, not necessarily the one with the maximum occurence` if the occurance of dates are in TIE,
rest of all other case it will give correct output

Comment: No, you have records per second. You aggregate them by minute. You say you want the maximum value for occurence (of all seconds in a minute). You also say you want an arbitrary tdate (of all seconds in a minute), because you have no aggregation function on tdate. A typical MySQL mistake.

Comment: when i run above query its seem give me correct count but tdate is totally wrong.

Comment: @Subin C Poonamgode: It may accidently work, yes, but still: In your inner query you select all seconds for a minute and count their occurrences. In your outer query you don't say which second to show. Another DBMS would force you to either have tdate in the GROUP BY list, which you don't want, or to use an aggregate function on it, but there is no appropriate aggregation function available in MySQL (such as Oracle's KEEP DENSE RANK FIRST).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Pardon me... You are right.. :) . I have edited  query can you take a look on that? looking forward for your reply

Comment: @BhavikPatel I have edited the query can ypu please check

Comment: No, this doesn't change anything. The order of the inner query's results is totally meaningless.

Comment: You new query looks quite fine. Only date + integer hours + integer minutes looks strange. I suppose that the date gets converted to integer, too, so you get 20151104+14+30 which is the same as 20151104+15+29 unfortunately. Did you mean to concatenate the parts as strings instead?

Comment: Oh.. i missed that.. Thanks for correcting me.. Looks like it working now as string.

Comment: where i need to pass where condition like date range ?

Comment: `T1.`tdate` BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-11-05'`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have the number of occurrences of each second first. From these you gather the maximum occurrence per minute. So you have seconds with their count and minutes with their maximum count. Then simply pick the seconds having their minute's maximum count:

I assume that your date column is of type DATETIME so it equals a second and can be used directly (otherwise you might have to cut off milliseconds, e.g. by applying `dateformat(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:&s')`).

```
select seconds.*
from
(
  select 
    dateformat(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as minute, 
    mydate as second, 
    count(*) as cnt
  from mytable
  group by mydate
) seconds 
join
(
  select minute, max(cnt) as max_cnt
  from
  (
    select 
      dateformat(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as minute, 
      mydate as second, 
      count(*) as cnt
    from mytable
    group by mydate
  ) counted
  group by minute
) minutes on minutes.minute = seconds.minute and minutes.max_cnt = seconds.cnt;
```

I don't have MySQL available and SQL fiddle doesn't work right now. So there may be errors in my query, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for nice work,
This query seems ok but like if no record in one minute like on 3rd Nov, 4th minute no record found ,should be return 0 record and where condition should be current day base.
so something like
where mydate from time is "2015-11-03 00:00:00 to 2015-11-03 23:59:59, and record should be return like 60(minutes) * 24(hours) = 1440 rows.

Comment: If i can pass where condition then it will be great.

Comment: You don't know where to place the WHERE clause? You put it where you select from your table of course, i.e. place `where trunc(mydate) = trunc(sysdate)` after `from mytable`. It should be fastest to put it in both subqueries, but as they are inner-joined you can as well decide to put it in one subquery only, so as not to have to write the same thing twice and thus enhance maintainability (but lose speed probably).

Comment: If you want to have minutes in your results that don't exist in your table, then you must create them (look up "generate rows" on how to do that). This would make your query less readable. You might prefer inserting missing minutes when displaying your results in whatever GUI and programming language you are using instead.

Comment: yes i tried where clause in both query and seems working thanks.